# Is it possible to install Sphinx after php, mysql etc.. have already been installed?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I'm confused

Does order matter when installing Sphinx Search. If mysql was already installed on my server, can I still install sphinx after or do I have to do them together or Sphinx before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use the SphinxSE engine in MySQL, you will need to recompile MySQL to include the engine.

Refer to this part of the manual: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#sphinxse-mysql50.  We didn't use the SphinxSE engine, we just used the PHP api client, and that we installed after having Apache/PHP/MySQL installed.

You will need to compile Sphinx yourself, but the method is given in that manual link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

It's more than just a PHP class... there's a search daemon and indexer that have to run on the server as well - but yes - it's often installed after mysql is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely you can install Sphinx after all.
The typical Sphinx client API - it's just a PHP class.